# $!=0 unclear syntax in perl

Tags: perl, syntax, proxy, socks

I am trying to understand this $!=0 , my supervisor gave me the cod in this link :http://codepaste.ru/1374/  but she has changed this part of cod:

```
    while($client || $target) {
      my $rin = "";
      vec($rin, fileno($client), 1) = 1 if $client;
      vec($rin, fileno($target), 1) = 1 if $target;
      my($rout, $eout);
      select($rout = $rin, undef, $eout = $rin, 120);
      if (!$rout  &&  !$eout) { return; }
      my $cbuffer = "";
      my $tbuffer = "";
 if ($client && (vec($eout, fileno($client), 1) || vec($rout, fileno($client), 1))) {
        my $result = sysread($client, $tbuffer, 1024);
        if (!defined($result) || !$result) { return; }
      }
```

to this :

```
while($client || $target) {
        my $rin = "";
        vec($rin,fileno($client),1) = 1 if $client;
        vec($rin,fileno($target),1) = 1 if $target;
        my($rout,$eout);
        select($rout = $rin,undef,$eout = $rin,120);
        break_pipe() if !$rout && !$eout;
        my($cbuf,$tbuf);
        if($client && (vec($eout,fileno($client),1) || vec($rout,fileno($client),1))){
            $! = 0;
            my $result = sysread($client,$tbuf,$packet_length);
```

I have searched but I did not find any thing like this syntax($!=0)in perl

Answer (score 2):

From Perldoc:

```
    $!

    When referenced, $! retrieves the current value of the C errno integer variable. 
    If $! is assigned a numerical value, that value is stored in errno . 
    When referenced as a string, $! yields the system error string corresponding to errno .

    Many system or library calls set errno if they fail, to indicate the cause of failure. 
    They usually do not set errno to zero if they succeed. 
    This means errno , hence $! , is meaningful only immediately after a failure
```

For more detail: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes `$!` is a variable for error status that may happen during the Perl program execution

as your question points to why `$!` tends to have value 0

I would like to add,

The initial value of errno (`$!`) before execution starts is zero.

Many library functions can set errno to a nonzero value as a result of calling other library functions which might fail. You should assume that any library function might alter errno.

Hope it helps. Also comment if any query

Answer (score 0):

[`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24!) contains the error number and error message of system calls on failure. Presumably, your new code looks like

```
$! = 0;
sysread(...);
if ($!) {
   # Error. Error message in $!
   ...
}
```

That's wrong. `sysread` has no obligation to leave `$!` untouched on success, so changing `$!` before calling `sysread` is useless.

If you want to check for an error, you check if the result of `sysread` is defined. If it's not, `$!` will be meaningful.

```
my $rv = sysread(...);
if (!defined($rv)) {
   # Error. Error message in $!
   ...
}
elsif (!$rv) {
   # End of file
   ...
}
else {
   # Data read
   ...
}
```